# Making columns directly under each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align columns under each other like this when the screen is lg or md: (this would by easy, I know.. Wait for the real problem :P)

[image]

BUT, when I go to a sm screen I want them to be like this.

[image]

Ive tried creating a bunch of loose columns like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    ...
</div>
```

But that makes it look like this:

[image]

I've thought about it for a while but just can't figure it out..

Is there an easy way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS 3 columns and media queries to control the number of columns across..

```
.row>.col-md-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

.row {
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    column-gap: 1.25rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .row {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .row {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/S9NFO9MpF5

Comment: Looks awesome! I'll try it out and accept the answer when I'm sure

Comment: Thanks! It works exactly how I wanted it to! Checked your awnser

Comment: (Also thanks for making this post look better, wasn't allowed to post images myself xD)